# WPF Caliburn.Micro and DXTabControl with UserControl not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to use a TabControl to switch between UserControls.

I could just set the content of the tabs to the usercontrols with XAML but then it will only be bound to the view and not the viewmodel.

My VM is a Caliburn.Micro Conductor and it calls ActivateItem whenever the user switches tabs. It worked fine when I only have one usercontrol, but when I created another one the first one will not load the view.

Here's some of the code I'm using:

ShellView:

```
<dx:ThemedWindow x:Class="PSCServiceManager.Views.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Title="Service Manager" WindowState="Maximized"
             Height="525" Width="720">

<Grid>
    <dx:DXTabControl>
        <dx:DXTabItem Header="Master Teknisi">
            <ContentControl x:Name="LoadMasterTechnicianView" cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}" />
        </dx:DXTabItem>

        <dx:DXTabItem Header="Servisan">
            <ContentControl x:Name="LoadServicesView" cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}" />
        </dx:DXTabItem>
    </dx:DXTabControl>
</Grid>
```

ShellViewModel:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace PSCServiceManager.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>
    {
        private MasterTechnicianViewModel masterTechnicianViewModel;
        private ServicesViewModel servicesViewModel;

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            LoadMasterTechnicianView();
        }

        public void LoadMasterTechnicianView()
        {
            ActivateItem(masterTechnicianViewModel);
        }

        public void LoadServicesView()
        {
            ActivateItem(servicesViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier/alternative way to implement this would be to create a collection of User Controls you would like to bind to the Tab Control. For example,

```
public interface ITabUserControl
{
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class MasterTechnicianViewModel : ITabUserControl
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = "Master Technician";
}

public class ServicesViewModel : ITabUserControl
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = "Services";
}
```

Now in your ShellViewModel, you could create a Collection of ITabUserControl

```
public List<ITabUserControl> UserControls { get; set; }
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        UserControls = new List<ITabUserControl>();
        UserControls.Add(new MasterTechnicianViewModel());
        UserControls.Add(new ServicesViewModel());
    }
```

And bind your TabControl as

```
 <dx:DXTabControl x:Name="UserControls"/>
```

Now you can switch between the controls without any issues, without Activating it explicitly.